# <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x279ceba2288>

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I build the following DL model based on Tensorflow/Keras
but it raises the following error

```py
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(263, input_dim=263, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Dense(56, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add( layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='class'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',loss_weights={'class':0.5}, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train,Y_train, epochs=20, verbose=0)
```

```
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x279ceba2288>
```

any one help  me why this error arises ???

is it related to tensorflow version?

Comment: This is not an error. `model.fit` returns a `History` object, which is what you're seeing. You can assign the output of `model.fit` to a variable, and you can use that `History` object later. It stores things like loss at each epoch.

Comment: Yes, this is not an error

Comment: Do you mind make a clean title for your post?

Answer (score 1):

I can be mistaken, but afaik keras.callbacks.history is just an output object from your fitting, so you can somehow use one specific 'fit' if you initialize your model multiple time